# Google maps Infowindow moves whole map position

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, infowindow

I am getting furious about this issue on my page using google maps API. 
When you clicked on markers (white with icon) the infowindow will be shown properly. However, when you click on the blue cluster, the infowindow will show but it moves the map position to ocean somewhere near Africa.
Have a look at the site: http://pec.solarismedia.net/map.html

Is there anyone who could explain me why that happens and how to avoid it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: double click it @MichaelGeary

Comment: @Filip the behaviour which you are mentioning can not be replicated on my chrome

Comment: Guys, so sorry about that by mistake I put online old version, when it didn't work completely. Have a look at it now, it does what I was trying to describe.

To make it absolutely clear, I am using Chrome 25 on Win7.
Thanks

Comment: Mystery solved! I will delete my older comments since they're no longer relevant.

Comment: Sorry about that kind of mystery ;)

Comment: "ocean somewhere near Africa": sound like (0,0) coordinates

Answer (score 1):

When you create the `InfoBox`, you are not giving it a `position` property which should contain a `LatLng`. I see two places in your code where you set up an `infoboxOptions` object which you pass to `new InfoBox()`, but neither one has a `position` property.

Because this is missing, the `InfoBox` defaults to a LatLng of (0,0). See this code in `gmap.infobox.js`:

this.position_ = opt_opts.position || new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0);

So you need to add a `position` property to your `infoboxOptions`. For the first one, it happens that you have a `myLatLng` variable that's initialized right above that code and used for the marker. If you want to use that same LatLng, then you could add this:

```
var infoboxOptions = {
    position: myLatLng,
    // and your other properties here
};
```

For the second one (the cluster), it looks like you have a reference to the `cluster` object, so you can call `cluster.getCenter()` to get its LatLng:

```
var infoboxOptions = {
    position: cluster.getCenter(),
    // and your other properties here
};
```

Comment: Wow, that was fast! But is it possible to get the coordinations out of as I do it with markers?

Like `cluster.infoboxCluster = new InfoBox(infoboxOptions);`

Thanks

Comment: Sure, you can get it from the `cluster` object, see updated answer.